# Дополнительные (бесполезные) ROLLBACK'и при использовании BasicDataSource из commons-dbcp

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Если экземпляр `BasicDataSource` из *Apache commons-dbcp* (версии 1.4, т. к. я ограничен Java 1.6) сконфигурирован с `defaultAutoCommit=false`, то библиотека выполняет два бесполезных `ROLLBACK`'а — один при взятии соединения из пула, и ещё один при возвращении его обратно (т. е. закрытии соединения из пула при сохранении низкоуровневого физического соединения открытым).

Соответствующие стек-трейсы (на примере `T4CConnection` драйвера *Oracle Thin*):

```
T4CConnection(PhysicalConnection).rollback() line: 1950 
PoolableConnection(DelegatingConnection).rollback() line: 368   
PoolableConnectionFactory.passivateObject(Object) line: 685 
BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(PoolableConnectionFactory) line: 1559 
BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory, KeyedObjectPoolFactory, AbandonedConfig) line: 1545  
BasicDataSource.createDataSource() line: 1388   
BasicDataSource.getConnection() line: 1044
```

и

```
T4CConnection(PhysicalConnection).rollback() line: 1950 
PoolableConnection(DelegatingConnection).rollback() line: 368   
PoolableConnectionFactory.passivateObject(Object) line: 685 
GenericObjectPool.addObjectToPool(Object, boolean) line: 1379   
GenericObjectPool.returnObject(Object) line: 1342   
PoolableConnection.close() line: 90 
PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close() line: 191
```

Т. обр., каждая успешная транзакция — это последовательность след. вида:

1. `ROLLBACK` (взятие соединения)
2. полезная работа с БД
3. `COMMIT` (прикладной код)
4. `ROLLBACK` (закрытие соединения)

(вместо единственного `COMMIT`'а), в то время как каждая неудачная — это:

1. `ROLLBACK` (взятие соединения)
2. полезная работа с БД
3. `ROLLBACK` (прикладной код)
4. `ROLLBACK` (закрытие соединения)

(вместо единственного `ROLLBACK`'а).

Вышеописанное поведение даёт дополнительную нагрузку на redo- и undo-подсистемы (что очень хорошо видно под нагрузкой в *Oracle*, но, на самом деле, при использовании *commons-dbcp* проблема универсальна — я наблюдал ровно то же самое и для, напр., *MySQL*).

**Вопрос 1**: как избавиться от пресловутых `ROLLBACK`'ов, сохранив экземпляр `DataSource` сконфигурированным с `defaultAutoCommit=false` (т. е. без необходимости вручную вызывать `setAutoCommit(false)` для каждого соединения, взятого из пула)?

**Вопрос 2**: как можно обойти проблему средствами *Oracle* (т. е. без необходимости менять прикладной код или библиотеки)?

Comment: Для оракла это бесполезная команда, так как бд не может работать в режиме autocommit в противоположность можно попробовать mysql и посмотреть как там будет работать.

Comment: Почему мешают эти откаты, или как  вы определи, что они создают дополнительную нагрузку?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что они бесполезные? Они очень даже полезны!